# Logging out from TabBarViewController to UIViewController using AccessToken

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, soap, uitabbarcontroller

I am facing problem in how to logging out from "TabBarViewController" to "UIViewController".
Firstly I am logging In(using SOAP web service + XML parsing) from UIViewController page, If the userId and Password is Correct then 'Access Token' is generated in database and(collected in variable using XML parsing in our page) and TabBarViewController is loaded(user profile page). Now after logging I want to "LogOut". On Profile Page I placed one button called "Logout".

Now here, I need your Help how to LogOut using 'Access Token'(which is generated during successful logging) So that I turn back to LogIn page agian ?????

Below is code is running when I Press "Login" button after entering "User ID" and "Password" in UITextField :

```
-(IBAction)Login{

   txtuser.text = @"test";
   txtpwd.text = @"test";

    if([txtuser.text isEqualToString:@"" ]|| [txtpwd.text isEqualToString:@""]) 
    {
        UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please fill all fields" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [myAlert show];
        [myAlert release];
    }
    else
    {

    md5 =[txtpwd text];

   //Calling MD5 Method to Convert password into "hashcode"(Hexadecimal) formate
    md5 = [md5 MD5];

    NSLog(@"%@",md5);
    itmselected =FALSE;
```

// Calling Web Service Method

```
    NSString *soapmessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                             "<soap:Body>\n"
                             "<Login xmlns=\"http://boleapp.com/\">\n"
                             "<UserName>%@</UserName>\n"
                             "<PassHash>%@</PassHash>\n"
                             "</Login>\n"
                             " </soap:Body>\n"
                             " </soap:Envelope>\n",[txtuser text],md5];
    NSLog(@"%@",soapmessage);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://weibotest.dotnetgeekz.com/servicemain.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

    NSString *msglength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapmessage length]];
    [req addValue:@" text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req addValue:@"http://boleapp.com/Login" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [req addValue:msglength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody:[soapmessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    webadata = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [txtuser resignFirstResponder];
    [txtpwd resignFirstResponder];   
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [webadata appendData:data];    
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"error");
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    xmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:webadata];
    [xmlparser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlparser parse];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Login"])

        soapresult = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    itmselected = YES;

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if(itmselected){
        NSLog(@"Bool value and Access Token Number and UserID= %@",string);

        if([string isEqualToString:@"false"]){
            [invaliduser setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"invalid_username.png"]];

        }
        else{
        NSArray* splits = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
        NSString *strbool = [splits objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *strAtoken = [splits objectAtIndex:1];
        id UserIdLogin = [splits objectAtIndex:2];
         if ([strbool isEqualToString:@"true"]){

             main.strAccessTokenMain = strAtoken; 
             main.UserIdMain = UserIdLogin;
             NSLog(@"strAccessTokenMain = %@",[main strAccessTokenMain]);

             // Calling "showtabbar" method for Loading TabBarViewController page
             [main showtabbar];      
        }
        }
        [soapresult appendString:string]; 
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"LoginResult"]){
        itmselected = NO;
    }
}
```

// "showtabbar" Method For Launching TabBarViewController

-(void)showtabbar{

```
//Removing UIViewController's 'Login' page
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[BoleApp release];

NSLog(@"userID = %@",UserIdMain);
tabbarcontroller = [[UITabBarController alloc]init ];

//Creating Object of "Profile" Class for Launching as First tab of TabBarViewController
profile *view1 = [[profile alloc]initWithNibName:@"profile" bundle:nil ];
view1.strAccessToken = strAccessTokenMain;
view1.UserIdProfile = UserIdMain;
NSLog(@"view1str = %@",view1.strAccessToken);
view1.title = @"Profile";
view1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"];   

//Second Tab of TabBarViewController
Brandslist *view2 = [[Brandslist alloc]init];
view2.BrandAccToken = strAccessTokenMain;
view2.UserIdBrndList = UserIdMain;
Instruction *view3 = [[Instruction alloc]init];
settings *view4 = [[settings alloc]init];
view2.title = @"Brands";
view2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brands.png"];

// Third Tab of TabBarViewController
view3.title = @"Info";
view3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"];

// Fourth Tab of TabBarViewController
view4.title = @"Settings";
view4.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"];
view4.AccessToken = strAccessTokenMain;
view4.user_ID = UserIdMain;

[tabbarcontroller setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1,view2,view3,view4, nil]];

[mainWindow addSubview:tabbarcontroller.view];
```

}

This is my profile page's "Logout" Method where I want to write code for Logging out from Profile page to Login page(UIViewController)

```
-(IBAction)Logout{
    NSLog(@"Logout Button Clicked !!!");
  // What to code here for resuming back to Login page ????? Please Help me out 
    ?
    ?
    ?
}
```

Friends, Please revert back. Your help would be appreciated . 
Thanks,
Tauseef Khan

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using, `[mainWindow addSubview]`, use `mainWindow.rootViewController = tabbarcontroller;`

This way, when pressing the logout button, you only need to add something like this:

```
mainWindow.rootViewController = loginViewController;
```

Using this, you are only changing the viewcontroller being displayed on the Main Window, and you can switch again to the tab bar controller in the same way, after a new login.

Comment: You need to remove all the [mainWindow addSubview:yourController.view] lines of code in your app and replace them with mainWindow.rootViewController = yourController.

Answer (score 0):

It would be convenient to show `loginViewController` as a modal view controller. This way you can always present modal `loginViewController` if server returns authorization error.

Comment: Can you elaborate it !! I didn't got what you are saying... @onegray

Comment: I think after user is logged out it needs to show Login screen again. Or user can become unauthorized unexpectedly, for example if auth token is expired. This way it might be helpful to show modal login screen that overlaps other app screens.

Comment: Yeah, you are thinking right... But I don't know how to expire Access token in my case... if you provide me code for that it would be great for me... As I already wasted more than 4 hour for resolving this issue... @onegray Help me to Help Others

Comment: How I understand simple login/logout idea:
Upon login request, server returns auth token. This token is stored in the app locally (for example in `NSUserDefaults`). And this token should be included with every other requests to the server.  Server might decide that token is expired, then it returns auth error. To make user logout manually, it needs just remove auth token from local storage.
In all cases if user is not authorized, it needs to show login screen and perform login request to get valid auth token.

Comment: I am storing 'Access token' in one "NSString" variable ... How to expire access token ?? any Idea ? This is am doing first time so having lots of confusion in it.. any code or help link ? @onegray  Thanks for your continued reply

Comment: How to expire access token ? Just remove it from local storage. If app does not have auth token then it means no one user is authorized and it needs to show login screen.